# Do I need to delete my git stash?

Tags: git, memory, git-stash

I have been using `git stash` to quickly discard all my changes on my local machine. At first I thought nothing of it but then I became concerned that it might start to fill up my hard drive on my machine, especially if I am stashing a lot of changes in many files.

Do stashes take up a lot of hard drive space on my local machine? Do I need to delete my git stash regularly?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, think of a stash as taking as much space as a commit. They're not that different, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just stashing changes to your source code, it will take a **loooooooong** time before you'll even notice the storage space the stash takes up. However, this is wasteful, and if you over do it, may cause a performance degradation to your git project, so clearing it is probably the right thing to do.

To quickly discard unwanted changes you could always use `git reset HEAD --hard`.